# Find a file within a for loop in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am attempting to find files to run commands against in a command prompt (batch) script. So far, so good:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R %%I IN ("*.Marker.txt") DO (
   SET MARKER=%%I
   SET LOG= ???

   ECHO MARKER IS !MARKER! AND LOG IS !LOG!
)
```

Basically, I want to iterate on a pair of files and execute a command on them (for now just `echo`). The problem I have is that the log file can be in any directory from where the `*.Marker.txt` file exists. I can't simply just say `100.Marker.log` because that's just the filename, not the full path. Some examples:

C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\100.Marker.txt
   C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\9\1\100.Marker.log
   C:\Temp\Samples\39B\122.Marker.txt
   C:\Temp\Samples\39B\2\5\122.Marker.log

So, not really sure what to do here.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer in case you find it helpful or leave feedback about it. See https://stackoverflow/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PUSHD`/`POPD` to push/pop the working directory during the script and an inner loop.

```
FOR /R %%I IN ("*.Marker.txt") DO (
   SET DIRECTORY=%%~DPI
   SET FILENAME=%%~NI
   SET MARKER=%%I

   PUSHD !DIRECTORY!
   FOR /R %%J IN ("!FILENAME!.log") DO (
     SET LOGFILE=%%J

     ECHO !MARKER!
     ECHO !LOGFILE!
   )
   POPD
)
```

Not sure how to find a single value, the `FOR` technically will run on all matches, but if you say you should only have a single value than the inner loop will only run once per marker file. Maybe there's a more efficient way to search for a single file without using `FOR`?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your files have the same format (`text.Marker.ext`), then you can use:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R %%A IN ("*.Marker.*") DO (
    set MARKER=%%A
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        set LOG=%%B
    )
   echo MARKER IS !MARKER! AND LOG IS !LOG!
)
```

Please note that I don't generally suggest capital letters in batch file.

- We make a loop that loops through all subfolders (`for /R`) trying to find files containing `.Marker.` (`IN ("*.Marker.*")`).
- We set the output to a variable (`MARKER`).
- Now, we loop through filename found setting `delims` to `.`. This means that: `token1.token2.token3`. `.` won't be parsed as a token.
- Set result to variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM following lines to create test environment
md C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\9\1 2>nul
md C:\Temp\Samples\39B\2\5 2>nul
break>C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\100.Marker.txt 
break>C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\9\1\100.Marker.log 
break>C:\Temp\Samples\39B\122.Marker.txt 
break>C:\Temp\Samples\39B\2\5\122.Marker.log
REM end creating test environment

for /R "C:\Temp\Samples\" %%a in ("*.marker.txt") do (
  for /f %%b in ('dir /s/b "%%~dpa\%%~na.log"') do (
    ECHO Textfile: %%a    Logfile: %%b
  )
)
```

The `for /R` looks recursively for all matching files (`*.marker.txt` in `C:\Temp\Samples\` and subfolders.
The `for /f` looks for matching log files below the folder, where the `marker.txt` is.

Output:

```
Textfile: C:\Temp\Samples\39B\122.Marker.txt    Logfile: C:\temp\Samples\39B\2\5\122.Marker.log
Textfile: C:\Temp\Samples\3A5\100.Marker.txt    Logfile: C:\temp\Samples\3A5\9\1\100.Marker.log
```

Note: this assumes, there is only one matching `.log` for each `.txt` and it's within the tree below `.txt`